# How to redirect a folder and its pages to a single page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect some files and I'm pretty stuck. There are way too many to do some of them on a "page-per-page" basis and so I need a quick way as these pages are insignificant but return 404's at the moment.

I have a page like this "/old-blog/tag/page", I previously redirected the "old-blog" to "new-blog" so I get "/new-blog/tag/page" but now I want "tag" and all pages after this to be sent to "new-blog". I hope this example makes sense, please ask if I've missed something.

I'm doing my redirects with my .htaccess file so I'd like a method I can use with this in mind.

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: This is what I've found so far, and I couldn't get it working:

redirectMatch 301 ^/cars/ http://www.mysite.com/things/stuff.html

Answer (score 0):

You may already have rewrite rules, if there are rules that do some type of routing, then mod_rewrite and mod_alias is going to conflict (`RedirectMatch` is mod_alias). So try sticking with just mod_rewrite. Try adding these rules, above any other rules, in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?old-blog/tag /new-blog/ [L,R=301]
```